# Find two text strings within N lines

Tags: windows, gratis, text-processing, plain-text

I am looking for a gratis Windows program that can take a standard windows text file and search for occurrences of two user provided strings within N lines of each other, where N is user specified.

`regex` is "nice to have", as are bells & whistles, but just that functionality will suffice.

[Update] I am looking for an off the shelf solution - not something that requires me to code.

Comment: No answer from me since I'm a  Mac user, but have you tried a web search. There are a lot of hits including https://www.lifewire.com/11-free-file-search-tools-1356644

Comment: Perhaps [NotePad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) matches. Is free, no coding, and has advanced search.

Answer (score 1):

[CudaText](http://www.uvviewsoft.com/cudatext/) is gratis. It can do it via custom Python plugin.

Plugin should show dialog via `dlg_input_ex()` or `dlg_input()`, user enters a number there, then plugin reads all lines via `ed.get_text_line(i)` and finds needed lines. Then it places caret via `ed.set_caret()` or shows found lines in `msg_box()`.

Comment: So, your recommendation is not a ready-made solution? It requires me to code? If I have understood that correctly, why would I not code my own stand-alone solution? Why do I need one of the many IDEs which support plug-ins? Using an IDE would constrain me. If I code a stand-alone app, it will do ***exactly*** what I want. As it is, I am looking for something off the shelf & will update the question to say so